# Translation for wordpress theme "Tarski"

Tags: wordpress, translation, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Tarski theme for a wordpress blog.
I want the blog to be french.

I looked at this page http://tarskitheme.com/help/localisation/, but I can't catch up how to use the .POT file to translate it in french.

I downloaded the file and opened it with geany, made all the translation, ex:

```
msgid "Search Results"
msgstr "Résultats de recherche
```

But then can someone explain to me what to do with this file? 
I suppose I have to rename it to tarski_3.0-fr_FR.pot, but then where do I put it? Do I have to "compile" it somehow?

Thank you all.

EDIT

It seems that I must ask a question here to find a answer by myself, I just find that I must generate .mo file from the .POT

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext#Translating

But I'm still don't know where to put this file... still searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply drop the .mo file in the root directory of your theme, and load the text domain. In your case, this last step is already done: the theme already loads its text domains (line 78 in functions.php, the function is [load_theme_textdomain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain)).

If you'd like a GUI for editing your translation and generating the .mo, try [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/).